# Como acceder a una posición de un ArrayList dentro un HashMap

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, hashmap

tengo un consulta si es que me pueden ayudar.
Quiero traer una posición concreta de una ArrayList que esta dentro de un HashMap como muestra la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una clase NoticialModel donde estoy usando los métodos Setters y Getters:

```
public class NoticiaModel {

private String titulo;
private String user;
private String link;
private String texto;
private String telefono;

private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> Fotos;

public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> getFotos() {
    return Fotos;
}

public void setFotos(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> fotos) {
    Fotos = fotos;
}

public String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public String getTexto() {
    return texto;
}

public void setTexto(String texto) {
    this.texto = texto;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public NoticiaModel(String titulo, String user, String link, String texto, String telefono, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> Fotos) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.user = user;
    this.link = link;
    this.texto = texto;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.Fotos = Fotos;
}


public NoticiaModel(){

}
```

}

Donde los llamo en otra clase para cargar un RecyclerView

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {

                            NoticiaModel model = document.toObject(NoticiaModel.class);

                            model.setTitulo(model.getTitulo());
                            model.setUser(model.getUser());
                           // model.setLink(model.getLink());

                            for(int i = 0; i < model.getFotos().size(); i++){
                                model.setFotos(model.getFotos());
                            }

                            model.setTexto(model.getTexto());
                            model.setTelefono(model.getTelefono());

                            noticias.add(model);

                        }

                        AdapterRecyclerView adapterRecyclerView = new AdapterRecyclerView(noticias, R.layout.cardview_picture, getActivity());
                        noticiasRecycler.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerView);
```

Y lo lleno de esta forma:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PictureViewHolder holder, int position) {

    noticiaModel = noticias.get(position);

    holder.tituloNoticia.setText(noticiaModel.getTitulo());
    holder.userNoticia.setText(noticiaModel.getUser());

    holder.texto.setText(noticiaModel.getTexto());
    holder.telefono.setText(noticiaModel.getTelefono());

    Glide
            .with(mContext)
            .load(noticiaModel.getFotos())
            .centerCrop()
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(holder.imagenCard);
}
```

Lo hice de esa forma pero me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo intente de varias formas, pero igual no me sale
Quisiera poder acceder a la posición 0 del ArrayList, para manejar su información.
Espero me puedan guiar con una ayuda, de antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: El error parece claro: solo se soportan Maps con claves String, no Integer.

Comment: Sí, gracias,  lo cambie por un String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas acceder a los elementos del `HashMap` mediante la posición una opción es convertir a List el `HashMap`:

```
  List<Objeto> indices = new ArrayList<Objeto>(myHashMap.values());
```

de esta forma podrías acceder a sus elementos en base a su posición en el Adapter:

```
System.out.println(indices.get(position + 1).getTitulo());
```

Se suma 1 ya que como sabes la posición inicia desde 0.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió perfectamente!!!

Comment: Excelente @JoseDanielMinchaca saludos!